# How do I stop Windows 7 from making noise every time I do a KVM switch?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Windows 7 knows when I change computers with my KVM switch and it plays a noise.  I can't figure out how to shut it off.  I can't figure out how to turn off Windows 7 sounds in general.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are probably hearing is the sound that plays when USB devices are connected or disconnected from the system. When you trigger the switch, the computer thinks you are disconnecting and reconnecting your mouse and keyboard, and plays the sound.

The sounds themselves are governed by the "Device Connect" and "Device Disconnect" program events. You can change or mute the sounds for these events in the Sound control panel.

Answer (score 6):

You can MUTE Windows 7 by clicking on the volume icon by the clock, then clicking on the speaker icon below the volume slider.

You can also go to `Control Panel`, then `Hardware and Sound`, then `Change system sounds` and set the `Sound Scheme` to `No Sounds`.

Answer (score 0):

An undocumented solution to mute a KVM click Shift Lk + Shift Lk + B.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is Shift Lk?